# How to make a scrolling pane in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I'm trying to design a HTML template with three rows: one header that always show at the top of the screen, one footer that always shows at the bottom of the screen and the remaining space for text, using a scrollbar when necessary.

The following HTML works fine in FF and Chrome, but doesn't show any text in IE9. Has someone an idea what is wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
<title>Image resize tetst</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body {
      margin:  0;
      padding: 0;
      height:  100%;
      width:100%;
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: table;
      height:  100%;
      width:100%;
    }

    .wrapper-row {
      display: table-row;
      width:100%;
      height:  1px;
    }

    .wrapper-content {
      /* Firefox requires this */
      display: table-cell;
      width:100%;
    }

    .wrapper-row-expanded {
      height:  100%;
      display: table-row;
    }

    .wrapper-row-expanded > .wrapper-content {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .scroll-container {
      /* Firefox requires this to do the absolute positioning correctly */
      display:    inline-block;
      overflow-y: auto;
      position:   relative;
    }

    .scroll-content {
      position: absolute;
      top:      0;
      bottom:   0;
    }
  </style>

</head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="wrapper-row">
        <div class="wrapper-content header">
        Header
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-row-expanded">
        <div class="wrapper-content scroll-container">
        <div class="scroll-content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vulputate pulvinar ullamcorper. Integer aliquet nunc vitae massa egestas ullamcorper. Nunc volutpat eleifend sem, a convallis lacus placerat eu. Curabitur venenatis ipsum in magna bibendum tincidunt. Donec nunc metus, pellentesque ullamcorper pellentesque sit amet, ornare vel est. Nam vehicula mi nibh. Praesent consectetur ipsum tincidunt nunc tincidunt eleifend luctus nisi viverra. Donec consequat, sapien ac semper tempus, quam metus pellentesque dui, ut dictum magna nibh eu magna. Nullam condimentum turpis vel mauris ornare vehicula. Maecenas a urna at turpis venenatis iaculis in nec nunc. Nunc tempus massa sit amet arcu malesuada ornare. Aenean pellentesque euismod quam vitae ornare. Maecenas sodales, mauris vel imperdiet eleifend, massa sem pellentesque justo, sit amet malesuada felis justo in elit.
            </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-row">
          <div class="wrapper-content footer" style="height:200px">
            Footer
          </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you used an iframed for the text and put it between the header and footer? that way you could add scrolling to the iframe if you had more text.

`<iframe src="URL" scrolling="yes"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:200px;
}
```

change height size according by you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't work; IE still doesn't show the content in the scroll-content div. It seems the scroll-content div has no height.

Comment: this only works as long as you a-priori know the height of the scroll container. But I want the scroll container to use all remaining space, i.e. the entire space between header and footer.

Comment: You can read .scroll-content height by jquery after page loaded. After, using jquery .css() append style for that.